# list(...) vs as.list(...) when using the triple dot argument

Tags: r, list, arguments

I would like to get a list with the "..." parameters passed to the function.

```
myfunction <- function(..., a=1){
  parameters <- as.list(...)
  for(i in parameters){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

But when calling `myfunction("x","y","z")` I get a vector with one item:

```
## [1] "x"
```

Howerver, if I replace `as.list(...)` by simply `list(...)`

```
myfunction <- function(..., a=1){
  parameters <- list(...)
  for(i in parameters){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

it works:

```
## [1] "x"
## [1] "y"
## [1] "z"
```

So why is `as.list(...)` behaving differently?

Cheers.

Comment: The triple dot argument has nothing to do with the behavior, compare the results of `as.list('x', 'y', 'z')` and `list('x', 'y', 'z')`. And look at `data.frame('x', 'y')` vs `as.data.frame('x', 'y')` too

Comment: `as.list` accepts a single `x` argument and `...` arguments passed to probable other methods; `as.list("x", "y", "z")` ignores "y" and "z" as they are seen as not used arguments and coerces "x" (i.e. `x` argument) to a "list". `list` accepts `...` arguments and builds a "list" on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for the `c` concatenate function.

```
as.list(c('x', 'y', 'z'))
#[[1]]
#[1] "x"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "y"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "z"

myfunction <- function(..., a=1){
  parameters <- as.list(c(...))
  for(i in parameters){
    print(i)
  }
}

myfunction('x', 'y', 'z')
#[1] "x"
#[1] "y"
#[1] "z"
```

I don't want to get the explanation wrong, so I'll let someone else explain why.